# jQuery addClass adds the class but I don't see a visual change in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using Angular 1.6 with jQuery 3.3.1 to practice Angular. My simple application screen looks like this.

[image]

In the event handler snippet below, I have a simple validation to check if the customer being added already exists in the system. If it does, I want to do 2 things:

1. Display an error message in red on top of the input fields. This happens nicely as you can see in the picture below.
2. Highlight the existing customer record in the list below the input fields by changing the background of the `<li>` to be red.

   $scope.onBtnAddNewCustomerClicHandler = function() {
       var customerId = $scope.customers.exists(
           $scope.newCustomer.name, 
           $scope.newCustomer.city);

   ```
   var listItem;
   if (customerId > 0) {
       // do the UI thing
       var listItem = angular.element(
         document.querySelector("#liCustomer_" + customerId));

       if (listItem === undefined) {
           throw new Error("Error: could not find the duplicate customer Id in the list of existing customers.");
       }

       $("#divErrorMessageSection").show();
       listItem.addClass("backgroundRed");
       return false;
   }
   else {
       $("#divErrorMessageSection").hide();
       if (listItem !== undefined) {
           listItem.removeClass("backgroundRed");
       }
   }

   $scope.customers.add();
   return true;
   ```

   };

My code works fine and does what it is supposed to, except I don't see any visual change indicating that the `<li>` background has turned red. However, I am able to change the class of the `<li>` to `backgroundRed` as indicated in the picture below.

[image]

The class gets added regardless of whether I use:

```
var listItem = angular.element(
          document.querySelector("#liCustomer_" + customerId));
```

or

```
var listItem = $("#liCustomer_" + customerId);
```

To look for the listItem containing the existing customer record.

My CSS looks like this:

```
.backgroundRed {
    background-color: red;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding !important in your css like below:

```
.backgroundRed {
    background-color: red !important;
};
```

Comment: There's no visible change yet even after adding that. Actually. I have a lot more CSS than I reported but I have stripped it down to its bare minimum to focus on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this a lot, according to my experience, css style tags are applied ONLY when the page loads. If you want to highlight the li tag, you have to change the style attribute.

The reason you don't see this on the error message is because the element is hidden until it shows, and is always red.

Try

```
listItem.style += "background-color: red";
```

Comment: That doesn't sit well with my many years of using jquery to add and remove classes in event listeners *long* after the page has loaded.